# p5.js multiple bouncing balls

Tags: p5.js

So I have a file with a class which describes a ball. And a main file which calls them and and them to the array. All I want to do is to bounce the ball back and forward, I can manage to do this with 1 ball, but then I add them more they are bouncing together (closest to the edge bounce all of them) all I want is to make them bounce individually. (Ball class and main code is in different files).

```js
// ball class ***********
let speed = 5;
class Ball {
  constructor() {
    this.x = mouseX;
    this.y = mouseY;
    this.r = 30;
    this.col = color(123, 125, 255, 50);
  }
  show() {
    stroke(255);
    fill(this.col);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
  }
  move() {
    if (this.y > height - this.r || this.y < 0 + this.r) {
      speed = speed * -1;
    }
    this.y = this.y + speed;
  }
}

//main code***********************
var balls = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i] = new Ball;
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].show();
    balls[i].move();
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    balls.push(new Ball);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `speed` outside your `Ball` class, which means it is shared between all `Ball` instances.

Move it inside the `Ball` class, exactly like you've already done with `x`, `y`, `r`, and `col`.

Also note that you should have `()` parentheses after a constructor. So `new Ball()` instead of `new Ball`.

Oh and one more thing, the loop in `setup()` isn't doing anything, because at that point your `balls` array has a `length` of `0`.